# How do computer science admissions committees process GRE essays sent with the scores?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science, writing, gre

I am currently studying for my GRE exam and I came across a book which states that GRE essays are sent with the official score reports. How does the admissions committee process these essays?

I am applying for a PhD in computer science.

Comment: Where did you see this information? To my knowledge, ETS does not send essays along with GRE test results.

Comment: @aeismail the answer by Rori confirms what I have read.

Comment: @ff524: is the field important to this question?

Comment: @Ooker Right now, the ability to access the essays is a relatively new feature, so I think it's unlikely that admissions committees in any field use it. But in the future, maybe admissions committees in some fields (but not others) will start to use it.

Comment: @ff524 as answered and commented below, no one (from humanity to hard science) cares about it because the schools require applicants to submit their own samples. Therefore, I don't think this is question is field-specific

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am surprised, but this does appear to be true.  From the [ets website](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/) we have the following:

> ETS also makes available test-taker photos and essay responses on the Analytical Writing section of the GRE® revised General Test to designated score recipients as part of an institutional portal. Photos and Analytical Writing essay responses of all individuals who report their scores to institutions on or after July 1, 2014, are included in the portal. The photo and essay responses from each GRE revised General Test administration you select from your five-year reportable history will be made available in the portal as part of your score record to the institutions you designated to receive your scores on or after July 1, 2014.

(In some sense, I'm even more surprised they are making photos of test-takers available.)  As for how the admissions committee processes these essays, others on the site can speak more directly to this, particularly in computer science.  However, I'm certain this will vary from department to department (assuming any department looks at them at all).  I suspect the admissions committee of many departments will not even be aware these essays are available through the ETS institutional portal.  Of those that are aware these exist, I would be surprised if much weight were placed on these.  These will convey almost no incremental information to an admissions committee.  (I suppose if you scored a 0 and the rest of your application was outstanding, and the committee knew these were available, someone might look to see what happened.  Maybe.)

Comment: I've read somewhere else that the essays are mostly for humanity researchers.

Comment: @Rori: The inclusion of photos is for fraud prevention.

Comment: @aeismail Right, I assumed as much.  I'm just surprised they are storing photos of every test-taker for 5 years and making that available to score recipients.  I can imagine some test-takers objecting to that.

Comment: @Ooker the essays would be thrown immediately in the trash bin in philosophy since you send a writing sample. The "analytic writing section' is ignored except in the case where it raises giant red flags. I can speak for other humanities.

Comment: @virmaior you would say *recycle bin* ;). Anyway, is that writing sample important, or can judging you better than the analytic? One can simply send the safest sample that they have, right?

Comment: First off, there's a missing *not* in my last sentence (I don't presume that level of arrogance -- I just mistyped it).

Comment: Second, I'm not in a position where I look at PhD applicants presently but the score given by non-philosophy graders would irrelevant as the writing sample is supposed to be the best possible philosophy paper you can write. Admittedly, that means it's presently an arms race where people send their "safest sample"  but the safest sample is one that shows the individual can make new contributions in philosophy either through a very solid critique or a noble attempt at a positive project.

Comment: The sort of things the analytic writing task tests (at least when I took it and scored a 6 in 2006 or 2007 were not nearly up to par.

Answer (score 6):

I'm on my department's graduate committee and read through all of the applications. I had no idea that the essays were available and am quite certain that my colleagues aren't either. The statement posted in one of the other answers also states that the essay is only available via a portal, which is not something you would typically go visit for each and every application.

Extrapolating from our department to all departments (certainly a sketchy process, though maybe not entirely crazy) I would say: don't worry about it -- nobody's going to read the essay.

Comment: if nobody is going to read the essay, then do they care about the score?

Comment: Yes. The essays were graded, so someone read it. We trust their judgment and just look at the number that the grader gave the GRE essay.